# How do i use RVM w/ Hudson CI server on Debian?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, hudson

I'm trying to setup an automated "build" server for my rails projects using Hudson CI. SO far it's able to run specs and do metrics on the code but I have 2 different projects dependent on 2 different versions of ruby. So i'm trying to use RVM to run multiple copies of ruby then switch back and forth in a pre-build step.

I found a couple posts like [this one](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2010/05/continuous-integration-multiple-ruby-versions-rvm-hudson/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AgileAjax+%28Agile+Ajax%29) that try and explain how to make this work, but I'm not running a startup script for hudson, it starts on boot which is how it worked out of the box when i installed it via the debian instructions.

The problem seems to be that even though hudson runs under the "hudson" account and that account has rvm installed (and working) when it tries to run a shell based prebuild step to call rvm switch 1.8.7 it fails with the error "rvm: command not found"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Hudson is using SH as its shell but i also tried using bash. no luck.

Has anyone gotten this working before in this setup?

Comment: What is `PATH` set to in `/home/hudson/.profile`? What does `type -a rvm` (Bash) or `which rvm` tell you?

Comment: $PATH is /usr/loca/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games

which rvm returns nothing but typing rvm executes the script. i believe rvm is a bash script not a actual application

type -a rvm returns "rvm is a function" and the function contents. 

in my .profile and .bashrc for the "hudson" user i have this line (per the hudson doc) 

if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ; fi

the weird thing is if i su to the hudson account i can use RVM but hudson server which runs on that account can't find it.

Comment: If the file `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` does not contain the statement `export -f rvm` then try adding it right before the `fi` that you referred to in your comment in both `.profile` and `.bashrc`. Also, when commenting to someone who is not the owner of an answer or question post, they may not see the comment or reply if you don't address it to them using @user (@Dennis in my case). Abbreviated user names work. Addressing in this way causes the little alert envelope at the top of the page to light up.

Comment: @Dennis no luck, Hudson still shows "rvm: command not found" when it tries to kick off a build. One thing worth noting, hudson is actually packaging up my commands into a temporary sh script and then executing that. I tried forcing it to run through /bin/bash but got a similar error. (p.s. thanks for the headsup about @ i didn't know that)

Comment: My next shot in the dark would be to create a script called `rvm` in `/usr/local/bin` with these contents: line 1: `#!/bin/sh`, line 2: `. /home/hudson/.rvm/scripts/rvm`, line 3: `rvm "$@"` and then do a `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin` and see if it works then. (I presume that's the correct path. If not then make it match what it should be.)

Comment: @Dennis different error. 

Now i get a bunch of permission denied errors like /usr/local/rvm/scripts/utility: line 188: /usr/local/rvm/config/system: Permission denied and some other random script errors like /usr/local/rvm/scripts/utility: line 327: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: reading the log further it actually ends up switching ruby version despite the errors but when the next scripts (the rake tasks) execute it runs them with the system version of ruby not the rvm version.

Comment: Have you added the `if [[ -s ... ]]; then source ... ` lines to `start_hudson.sh`? (And remove the script I suggested earlier). I didn't look at the site you linked to until just now. It looks like they're having some issues getting this process working. Perhaps your problem is related. Other than checking to see if the owner, group and permissions of the new `rvm` wrapper script are reasonable, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same symptoms as you.

After a couple of hours of headbanging, check your $HOME environment variable for Hudson (viewable at http://yourserver/hudson/systemInfo).

Under Ubuntu, the Tomcat 6 start script doesn't set $HOME. Somehow, Hudson inherited my $HOME instead!

I added HOME=$CATALINA_HOME to the `/etc/init.d/tomcat6` script just under the rest of the ENV declarations, and now it all works. Very annoying issue, to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

edit the "/etc/init.d/hudson" (!) and change the line:

```
SU=/bin/su
```

... change to:

```
SU="/bin/su -"
```

... and add rvm setup in the /home/hudson/.profile